# Searching Single-board computer

Tags: linux, ethernet

I already googled bit around but didn't find something that really fits my expectations... My budget is around $100 and my requirements would be

- USB 3.0 Port(s)
- Gigabit Ethernet (min)
- SSD and / or microSD slot
- at least 1 GB RAM

and would be mainly used for

- Media Server / LMS
- Owncloud
- Internal Website

Do you know any single-board computers that would fit these requirements?

I'm confused why the most recent versions of Raspberry Pi and similars only have 512 MB of RAM. Is that really enough??

Comment: Raspberry Pi 3 has 1 GB of RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just one [example](http://www.orangepi.org/orangepiplus2/): **[The Orange Pi Plus](http://www.orangepi.org/orangepiplus2/)**

It has -

- Gigabit ethernet
- 2 GB RAM
- SATA 2.0 interface
- TF card slot

It doesn't have USB 3.0

> What can I do with Orange Pi Plus2?
>
> Build…
>
> A computer
>
> A wireless server
>
> Games
>
> Music and sounds
>
> HD video
>
> A speaker
>
> Android
>
> Scratch
>
> Pretty much anything else, because Orange Pi Plus2 is open source
>
> Who’s it for?
>
> Orange Pi Plus2 is for anyone who wants to start creating with technology – not just consuming it. It's a simple, fun, useful tool that you can use to start taking control of the world around you.